# Can you make an Extension Method Static/Shared?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

OK, I've probably misunderstood something here but, as far as I can see ...

- An extension method has to be contained in a module, not a class
- You can't make methods in modules Static/Shared
- Therefore you can't use an extension method on a class without instantiating it.

In other words you can't make an extension method on String called "MyExtensionMethod" and use:

```
String.MyExtensionMethod("String")
```

But instead ..

```
Dim test As String
test.MyExtensionMethod("string")
```

Is this correct? Or is there a way I can get extension methods to work as static methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct. Extension methods can only act on instances of a type.

And no, unfortunately there's no crafty way to write extension methods that act on the types themselves, behaving like static methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like an incredible oversight though, since most "helper type" functions on existing framework objects function as static :(