# How do I extend THE class, not the instance?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you make an Extension Method Static/Shared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880773/can-you-make-an-extension-method-static-shared)

Extension methods are great!
Pardon my ignorance, but so far I've only found that you can extend a class to allow methods on its instances, but not the class itself.

Here's what I'm trying to do.
I have an enum like so:

```
enum ViewType
{
    Front_View,
    Back_View
}
```

And I already created an extension method `ToDescription()` to display a user-friendly textual representation of the view type, like so:

```
ViewType thisview = ViewType.Front_View;
string thisviewtext = thisview.ToDescription();  // translates to "Front View"
```

But later in the code, I want to parse from that translation back to the type, like this potential code if assuming I can extend the enum type itself:

```
// !!!NOT REAL CODE YET!!!
// translate to value ViewType.FrontView
ViewType newview = ViewType.ParseFromDescription("Front View");
```

How do I implement that `ParseFromDescription(string)` extension method (if possible)?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is totally doable in languages like Ruby. If you are craving this kind of control, a more liberal language might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a static method callable as if it were contained in another static class. You cannot, for instance, create a String.IsNullOrBlank() function that checks the passed string for only whitespace in addition to being null or zero-length. You would have to have access to the String class code and add the method there.

To get the result you want, I would start with the string and implement an extension method ParseDescriptionToViewType() that will take the string as its "this" parameter and output the ViewType.

Comment: I like your answer on two accounts.

Comment: First, the bottom line of "you can't extend a static method, only instance methods".

Comment: Second, thinking out of the box and extending the string instance to go back to the ViewType enum.  I like that!

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. You could define a static helper class ViewTypeTools containing the method. Extension methods are basically the same thing, but a bit nicer to write.

Comment: And the OP presumably already has that class, since he has the extension method .ToDescription() defined somewhere.

Comment: Exactly. Related to the question, I'm sometimes disappointed at how little features an enum has. I once solved a similar problem by adding description attributes to every enum value, but you'd have to resort to using reflection then, which I try to avoid if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (kludgy) that I didn't test but I think will work

```
((ViewType)null).ParseFromDescription( "Front View" );

// defined like 
public static ViewType( this ViewType me, string description )
{
    // ignore the 'this' parameter, just parse etc ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't the first line a null-pointer exception even at compile-time (half a joke)?

Comment: nope, because the compiler will change it to `ViewTypeExtension.ParseFromDescription(null, "Front View");` for you.  As long as you ignore the first param inside your function (or do things that are valid for null), you will be fine.